# Is autoscan of Spring Configuration classes possible by ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have multiple configuration Configuration classes (@configuration) classes in my application in multiple maven modules.
However I will use a single instance of AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to register these configuration classes.

Do I have to manually call and register the classes as shown below?

```
ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ac.register(conf1);
ac.register(conf2);
```

...

or Do we have a way to autoscan the configuration classes?
Looking for something like componentscan but at the ApplicationContext level.

Comment: Use `@ComponentScan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it. Either scan using the method on AnnotationConfigApplicationContext for example

```
ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ac.scan("com.sample.service" , "com.sample.dao");
ac.refresh();
```

Alternatively register at least one @Configuration class using register method which in turn uses @ComponentScan to include classes from specific locations

Comment: Will this work if the packages are across different maven modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in your web.xml. 
The param-value on context-param is where you define the location of your config files. If there are multiple locations, it can be added as comma-separated.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/location/of/configfiles</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: Mine is a server project.Therefore no web.xml. Looking for a annotation based or java solution.